# How to get text contents of google document via google drive REST api

Tags: java, rest, google-drive-api

I need to read data from a google drive document (MIME Type: application/vnd.google-apps.document) so that I can pass it further downstream for processing.

It looks like the only way to do this is to first download the document using `files().export(fileId, MIME_TYPE.GoogleDocsDocument.toString()).getMediaHttpDownloader`
, parsing the contents after downloading, and then uploading a new file with the contents of that document using files().update

Ive tried using 
`files().get(fileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream)` but it doesn't allow google files.  I've also tried digging around their documentation for other ways to do this, but have had no luck so far.

Is there no way to avoid downloading the file?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was trying to export the document as a google doc, which is why I was getting errors when trying to use the executeMediaAndDownloadTo method.  Exporting as plaintext or some other non google format seems to be necessary for this.  I'm sure this will cause some kind of formatting issues, but it should be possible to work around those.  Here is a basic usage of what I've ended up with.

```
    public void updateGoogleDocFile(String fileId, String newContent) throws IOException
{
    try {
        //First retrieve the file from the API as text file
        java.io.File tempDataFile = java.io.File.createTempFile("googleDocsIncomingFile", ".txt");
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempDataFile);
        //Convert data to bytes and write to new file
        byte[] fileBytes = downloadGoogleDocFile(fileId).toByteArray();
        os.write(fileBytes);
        //Get new data to append, convert to bytes, and write to file
        byte[] newConentBytes = newContent.getBytes();
        os.write(newConentBytes);
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        //File's new metadata.
        File newFile = new File();
        //newFile.setName(fileName);
        //newFile.setDescription("mydescription");
        //newFile.setMimeType(MIME_TYPE.GoogleDocsDocument.toString());

        // Send the request to the API.
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(MIME_TYPE.GoogleDocsDocument.toString(), tempDataFile);
        SERVICE.files().update(fileId, newFile, mediaContent).execute();

      } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("An error occurred while trying to update the google docs file: " + e);
      }
}

public ByteArrayOutputStream downloadGoogleDocFile(String fileId) throws IOException
{
    Export export = SERVICE.files().export(fileId, MIME_TYPE.PlainText.toString());
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    export.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
    return out;
}
```